# fputs() newline behaviour in c

Tags: c

Having trouble understanding a program(below).
I am little bit confused about the statement `fputs("\n",fp)`
eg. let me type:

> It doesn't matter what you are underneath
>   Its what you do that defines you.

If I don't mention `fputs("\n",fp)` the string appears in a single line. But with the code it is saved as typed.

Now the question is how the `\n` is inserted in the desired place, cause' normally the `\n` should be appended in the end of the text.

Any help would be seriously appreciated.

```
int main()

{
    FILE *fp;

    char s[80];
    fp=fopen("abc.txt","w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    { 
            puts("Cannot open file");
            exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nEnter a few lines of text:\n");
    while(strlen(gets(s))>0)
    {
          fputs(s,fp);
          fputs("\n",fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fputs writes the string you give it, it does not append any characters to that string. puts, on the other, does append a newline. It's an inconsistent api.

Comment: Thinking of it, this difference is the same between gets() and fgets() (in addition to fgets() allowing a buffer size).

Comment: If you see the error `Type "char" is not compatible with parameter type "const char*"`, make sure you used double-quote marks `"\n"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`gets` (which shall not be used and has actually been removed from the most recent C standards) does not save the `\n` in its buffer (while `fgets` does).

And `fputs`, unlike `puts`, does not automatically insert one at the end of the string it writes. So by adding a `fputs("\n", fp);` (or `fputc('\n', fp)`) after outputting each typed line, you insert the missing newline in the file.

Answer (score 4):

`fputs` does not automatically add a newline to the output (in contrast with `puts` which does).